# Drop multiple databases in one script

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, psql, scripting

I am trying to figure out how to drop multiple databases on PostgreSQL in one sql script. I preferably need it to work both when executed in `pgAdmin` console, and when used in `psql` command line tool. When I do:

```
DROP DATABASE db1;
DROP DATABASE db2;
```

I get following error:

> DROP DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string

Is there any way around this problem? I.e., is there any way to run each command separately (like when using "GO" statement on MSSQL), or some other sensible way to easily drop multiple databases? I need this functionality for maintenance scripts during development.

Comment: There is a workaround ... USE [master] GO SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ['+name+']' FROM sys.databases WHERE name like N'StartsWith_%' Then copy the result to a new query, review the list and hit F5.

Comment: This code looks like something for SQL Server.  The question is about PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When executing multiple commands in a script in ***pgAdmin*** they are automatically wrapped into a transaction. You can explicitly `begin` and `commit` transactions, but not with commands that won't run in a transaction context. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html)

> `DROP DATABASE` cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

Similar in ***psql*** when called with `-c command`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

> If the command string contains multiple SQL commands, they are
>   processed in a single transaction, unless there are explicit
>   `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands included in the string to divide it into
>   multiple transactions.

**However**, when fed to ***psql*** via standard input:

> This is different from the behavior when the same string is read from
>   a file or fed to psql's standard input, because then psql sends each
>   SQL command separately.
>
> Because of this behavior, putting more than one SQL command in a
>   single `-c` string often has unexpected results. It's better to use
>   repeated `-c` commands or feed multiple commands to psql's standard
>   input, either using echo as illustrated above, or via a shell
>   here-document, for example:
>
> ```
> psql <<EOF
> \x
> SELECT * FROM foo;
> EOF
> ```

So you can use psql with standard input in default [*autocommit-on* mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES).
Else, you can only run **separate commands**.

You could use the shell-command [`dropdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-dropdb.html) - or write a shell-script with it that drops multiple databases.

BTW, the only difference between what you can run from pgAdmin and psql are the [meta-commands of psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) - which are not SQL. Those are interpreted by psql and not the database engine. To switch between meta-commands and SQL, use the separator meta-command `\\`. There is an [example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).